# limit superior of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am considering the following problem:

> For any continuous stochastic process $\{ X_t \}_{t \geq 0}$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Suppose that $\limsup_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{E} [X_t] = + \infty$. Does this imply that $$ \limsup_{t \to \infty}  X_t =+ \infty \quad \quad \text{ almost surely}?$$

It seems to be a very natural fact intuitively, but I cannot find a way to prove it rigorously, nor can I find a counterexample to disprove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is not true. For example you could take $$X_t =X$$ for any $t \ge 0$ with X being a random variable distributed according to the PDF
$$p(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} 1_{\{ x\ge 1\} }$$
Then $\mathbb{E}[X] =\mathbb{E}[X_t] = + \infty$ but the process is constant and finite.